# How do I acces/open a default application in different devices

Tags: android

I am currently working on a **Launcher Activity**(min SDK version:7), and stumbled upon a serious issue. Is there any **EFFICIENT METHOD** by which I could access/open a **Default App** (like the dialer, browser, sms conversation list, email client, system settings,etc),which are commonly found in different devices(like ***Samsung***, ***HTC***, ***Sony***, ***LG***, ***Motorola***, etc), but have different package names.

I know that I can access them by calling an intent, For example I could open the ***Default SMS Client*** like so:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");
                intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.android.mms","com.android.mms.ui.ConversationList"));
                startActivity(intent);
```

But the package name differs when it comes to different manufactures(like the ones mention above)
ie in the case of opening the ***sms client of motorola devices*** the code changes so:

```
Intent moto_intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");
                intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.motorola.blur.conversations","com.motorola.blur.conversations.ui.ConversationList"));
                startActivity(moto_intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an [implicit](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidIntent/article.html#intents_implicit) intent (instead of an explicit intent).

In your case, you'd use the [ACTION_SEND](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_SEND) intent

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.putExtra("address", "5551234567");
intent.putExtra("sms_body", "Hi mom");
// intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imageUri);          
// intent.setType("image/jpeg");
startActivity(intent);
```

This method will also work for users who prefer to use their own third party SMS application.

Comment: Thank you Stephan, but I don't want to lead my users to any third part sms app. I just want to lead him/her to the default application (in this case the sms client) provided by the device.

Comment: If the user doesn't have any third party app installed, the implicit intent will lead him/her straight through to that default system application. If the user does have a third party app installed, the user will be asked to make a choice, but I don't see why that would be bad. Why should I as a user be forced to use the default system sms application when I use a different one on a daily basis? In any case, I suppose you could try explicit intents first (the ones you know about at least), and if those are not there, you could fall back to an implicit intent.